# Evaluate sexp and display output in new buffer in grep-mode

Tags: emacs, lisp

Following [this recipe](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode#toc19), I have prepared this search command:

```
(shell-command "grep . /tmp/listoffiles | xargs grep -n mystring" 1)
```

And if I run this with `eval-last-sexp` (<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>), a list with the matches will appear right after the command, in the same format recognized by buffers in `grep-mode`. But this buffer is *not* in `grep-mode` so I can not jump automatically to the desired file/line.

What I would like is the following: I will use a buffer where to enter my search commands; going to the end of one of those commands, and pressing a key combination will trigger a function `run-grep-in-other-buffer`. This function must perform the following actions:

1. Evaluate the search command at `point`, as done by `eval-last-sexp`
2. Create a **new** buffer
3. Output the result of the search command in the new buffer
4. Set the new buffer in `grep-mode`
5. Activate the new buffer.

My `lisp` is really limited. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show the contents of file `/tmp/listoffiles` for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function directly instead of your construction with shell-command:

```
(defun run-grep-in-other-buffer (str)
  (interactive)
  (let ((grep-host-defaults-alist nil)
        (grep-command str))
    (call-interactively 'grep)))
```

Run this with `eval-last-sexp`:

```
(run-grep-in-other-buffer "grep . /tmp/listoffiles1 | xargs grep -n list")
(run-grep-in-other-buffer "grep . /tmp/listoffiles2 | xargs grep -n list")
```

Comment: what does `eab` stand for? (I assume it is an acronym you use)

Comment: You can use your name for function, e.g. `run-grep-in-other-buffer`. `eab` is just unique identificator for my functions.

Comment: Does this mean that a `let` binding will shadow the global value for `grep-host-defaults-alist` even in the called function (`grep-command`)?  I guess this is what lexical scoping would disable?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong: `lexical-let` isn't like `let` with `;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-`. But if I define function `run-grep-in-other-buffer` when `lexical-binding` is `t` then it works as usual, I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe because "For the simple examples given above both lexical and dynamic binding return the same results" http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding